# Is there a free QR code reader for Mac?

Tags: snow-leopard, webcam

Is there a QR-Code reader application for Mac OS X? I'm using Mac OS X 10.6 and an iSight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an Adobe Air application you can download called [QR Reader](http://dansl.net/QRreader.air) - works on any platform that has Air installed, and a bunch of online services you could try too - [QRGen](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/qrgen/) looks pretty neat - you upload an image of the QR code and then it processes it for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried QRGen but it didn't manage to resolve the QR Codes which I uploaded. But I think your answer is still acceptable as there could be quality issues with the QR Codes I took pictures off ;)

Comment: Have you tried QR Reader as well? Might work better. I've tried QRGen with pictures taken on my iPhone 4 and it worked 4 times in a row. Maybe you are right about the resolution issues. Hope you can get it worked out. Cheers.

Comment: When QR Reader detects a URL, it automatically opens a browser window and does not give you the option of *not* opening that window. I hate computer programs that presume what I want to do and then do it, especially when it is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 9):

I just discovered [QR Journal](http://www.joshjacob.com/mac-development/qrjournal.php), which works fine for me. The latest version requires OS X 10.8/10.9 but there is a legacy version available which works with 10.6.

> Now desktop users with an iSight (or iSight compatible) camera can read QR codes. Found a QR code in a magazine or catalog? Simply hold up to the iSight camera to scan, store and browse to. Received a QR code in an email? Just drag it into QR Journal to read it.

Comment: Sadly, for my purposes, my MacBook Pro's camera can't focus near enough for the QR codes to be readable. :(

Comment: Worked very well for me to read QR wifi code from my android to my mbp.

Comment: `brew install --cask qr-journal` , see https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/qr-journal .

Comment: How do I know if my Mac has an iSight camera? It's a new M1 MacBook Air and there's no iSight app...

Answer (score 6):

There is an open source [command line tool named ZBar](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar). It takes a photo as an argument and extracts the information out of any QRCode that it detects in the image.

The open source project [QR-Reader-Mac](https://github.com/FrederikRogalski/QR-Reader-Mac) provides an Applescript script that acts as a wrapper to `zbar`. You can create a shortcut to the script for processing QRCodes or create a service, as explained below. The script will automatically open the URL contained within the QRCode in your default browser.

### Usage

[image: qrreader]

### Step by step

ZBar can be easily installed with Homebrew:

```
brew install zbar
```

To install QR-Reader-Mac:

1. Open the [QR-Reader-Mac GitHub project page](https://github.com/FrederikRogalski/QR-Reader-Mac), select Code and download the project as a ZIP file:

   [image]
2. Double click the ZIP file to extract it.
3. Double click the workflow you want to install. The following Pop-UP should appear:
4. Confirm by pressing `install`.
5. Open System Preferences and add a shortcut to the open_QRCode service under Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > General:
   [image]

(**Important**: Note that QR-Reader-Mac expects to find the executable 'zbarimg' in `/usr/local/bin/zbarimg`, which is the standard path Homebrew will install it.)

### Copy to Clipboard

The `QRCode2Clipboard.workflow` can be used to extract the content of the QR-Codes into the Clipboard. It can be installed in the same way as the `open_QRCode.workflow`.

Answer (score 4):

No free app that I'm aware of, but for a few dollars/euro you can download QuickMark from the Mac App Store, [here's the link](http://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/quickmark/id412378487?mt=12)

Comment: Since someone down-voted this, it would be helpful if they commented to say why.  The app I've linked to does exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: I think it's because the poster asked for a free app.  QuickMark does look good and reasonably priced though.

Comment: My mistake, you're right.  I read the question and not the title.

Comment: I'd be inclined to download since it doesn't work reliably.

Comment: This app is not available from the UK app store FWIW.

Comment: It used to be, but that was 7 years ago 

Answer (score 2):

**Online encode/decode:**

http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/qrgen/ (based on ZXing)

QR Lab
http://www.onlineqrlab.com/

Comment: http://www.onlineqrlab.com/ is not working at the moment

Answer (score 1):

The app that worked flawlessly in my macOS Big Sur is this: https://apps.apple.com/ie/app/code-reader-qr-scanner/id1225393668

I tried QR Journal, as suggested by others here, but for some reason the camera didn't detect the QR code so I ended up finding the other app.

*Note: I am in no way affiliated with either of these apps.*

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but **LensOCR** is *exactly* what I needed. I use it solely for the barcode/QR scanning feature.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lensocr-extract-text-image/id1549961729

It allows me to screenshot a portion of my screen containing a barcode or QR code and instantly saves the result to the clipboard. I know OP asked for free... *but* when you find the right app that you will use a ton the $11.99 one-time cost is justified in my book.

> **Note:** The original question implies the use of a webcam for scanning.
> The app I recommended above does *not* use the webcam at all. It just
> interprets screenshot content.

Answer (score 0):

I've just download this; seem to work exactly as you'd want:

https://github.com/julianschiavo/JSScan